# How to set the storage on taquito application?

Tags: node, taquito

I'm using this smart contract: https://github.com/claudebarde/taquito-pinata-tezos-nft/blob/main/contract/NFTS_contract.mligo

I can deploy it on the https://ide.ligolang.org/ using the storage they have commented out at the end of the contract, copy-paste the contract (KT...) to my taquito application and everything works.

But, I want to deploy it and provide the storage directly in my taquito/jsligo application, but I have no idea how to declare/set/assign the store.

e.g.

```
import {  TezosToolkit } from "@taquito/taquito";
import { importKey } from "@taquito/signer";
import { RPC_URL } from "./utils/constants";
import { InMemorySigner } from "@taquito/signer";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();
const Tezos = new TezosToolkit(RPC_URL);
const privateKey = process.env.WALLET_PRIVATE!;


importKey(Tezos, privateKey);
// generic.json is referring to Michelson source code in JSON representation
const genericMultisigJSONfile = require("../smart_contract/samples/fa_2.tz");

const storage = /* I have no idea */

function sign() {
  Tezos.setProvider({ signer: new InMemorySigner(privateKey) });

 
  Tezos.contract
    .originate({
      code: genericMultisigJSONfile,
      storage: storage,
    })
  .then((originationOp) => {
    console.log(
      `Waiting for confirmation of origination for ${originationOp.contractAddress}...`
    );
    return originationOp.contract();
  })
  .then((contract) => {
    console.log(contract);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}`));
}

sign();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these steps to originate the contract with Taquito: https://tezostaquito.io/docs/originate/

Regarding the initial storage, you can use this JavaScript object:

```
import { MichelsonMap } from "@taquito/taquito";

const initialStorage = {
  ledger : new MichelsonMap();
  operators : new MichelsonMap();
  reverse_ledger: new MichelsonMap();
  metadata: new MichelsonMap();
  token_metadata: new MichelsonMap();
  next_token_id: 0;
  admin: VALID_TEZOS_ADDRESS;
}
```

This will originate a new contract with empty bigmaps. There is no need to type the bigmaps, Taquito will figure it out :)